# Issue On Creating Dictionary From JSON

Tags: c#, json, json.net, treeview

I am able to load REST JSON into an array. But I need to load the data as a Dictionary to access both `name` and `type` so can display them in the `treeView1`

the json looks like

```
{"currentVersion" : 10.05, 
  "folders" : [], 
  "services" : [
    {"name" : "appData/Drainage", "type" : "MapServer"}, 
    {"name" : "appData/Parks", "type" : "MapServer"}, 
    {"name" : "appData/Planning", "type" : "MapServer"}, 
    {"name" : "appData/QNet", "type" : "MapServer"}, 
    {"name" : "appData/Sanitary", "type" : "MapServer"}, 
    {"name" : "appData/Street_Lights", "type" : "MapServer"}, 
    {"name" : "appData/Survey", "type" : "MapServer"}, 
    {"name" : "appData/Transportation", "type" : "MapServer"}, 
    {"name" : "appData/Water", "type" : "MapServer"}
  ]
}
```

Using this code, I am able to display only `name` on treevView

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServiceResponse>(json);
var servicesList = model.services.Select(s => s.name.Replace("app/", "")).ToArray();
foreach (string value in servicesList)
{
    treeView1.Nodes.Add(value);
}
```

like:

[image]

but I need to have something like

[image]

I alreadytried adding dictionary like this

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
```

bot not sure how to retrieve data from there and apply to `treeView1`?

Comment: have you considered mapping to a data structure instead?

Comment: Thanks for reply Daniel, but can con you please let me know what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to retrieve such kind result from JSON that you provided you can try something like this

Not sure what `ServiceResponse` is, so I've created it, just for demo

```
string json = @"{'currentVersion' : 10.05, 
    'folders' : [], 
    'services' : [
        {'name' : 'appData/Drainage', 'type' : 'MapServer'}, 
        {'name' : 'appData/Parks', 'type' : 'MapServer'}, 
        {'name' : 'appData/Planning', 'type' : 'MapServer'}, 
        {'name' : 'appData/QNet', 'type' : 'MapServer'}, 
        {'name' : 'appData/Sanitary', 'type' : 'MapServer'}, 
        {'name' : 'appData/Street_Lights', 'type' : 'MapServer'}, 
        {'name' : 'appData/Survey', 'type' : 'MapServer'}, 
        {'name' : 'appData/Transportation', 'type' : 'MapServer'}, 
        {'name' : 'appData/Water', 'type' : 'MapServer'}
    ]
}";

var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServiceResponse>(json);

var services = model.Services.Select(t => new Service
{
    Name = t.Name.Replace("appData/", ""),
    Type = t.Type
}).OrderBy(t => t.Name).ToList();

foreach (var service in services)
{
    string value = $"{service.Name} - ({service.Type})";

    //treeView1.Nodes.Add(value);

    Console.WriteLine(value);
}


public class ServiceResponse
{
    public string CurrentVersion { get; set; }
    public List<string> Folders { get; set; }
    public List<Service> Services { get; set; }
}

public class Service
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Note about [`Enumerable.Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx) it projects each element of a sequence into a new form.
In your case `servicesList` is just Array of Strings that you've returned from that expression.